# Mysql ,how to add two new columns and insert data at the same time?

Tags: mysql

It's my code

```
alter table num_of_people add column date_pre varchar(40);
alter table num_of_people add column time_pre varchar(40);
```

The result like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSYzN.jpg)

But I can't insert new data into these two columns：

```
insert into num_of_people(date_pre,time_re) select left(Deal_time,8),right(Deal_time,2) from num_of_people;
```

Nothing happened:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ3Ss.png)

I create a new table,that's worked:

```
create table Date_time(
 date_p varchar(40),
 time_p varchar(40)
);

insert into date_time(date_p,time_p) select left(Deal_time,8),right(Deal_time,2) from num_of_people;
```

So,Why?
I just want to split the charactor in column `Deal_time` of table `num_of_people`. What's the better way? I am a novice in MySQL.Thanks a lot.

Comment: that's because with your second query `insert into num_of_people(date_pre,time_re) select       left(Deal_time,8),right(Deal_time,2) from num_of_people;` you inserted new rows where you only added `date_pre` and `time_re`. if you wanted to update the older rows you need to use `UPDATE`. i bet you'll find the missing values where `Deal_time` is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your images, you should perform an `Update` query instead of `Insert` to the table `num_of_people`.

To explain why you can't insert new data into those two columns, my best guess is that at least one of your existings columns must be a `NOT NULL` column that has no explicit `DEFAULT` value defined. Even if you succeeded in executing the `Update`, the total number of your table's records would be doubled.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html

> For data entry into a NOT NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT
>   clause, if an INSERT or REPLACE statement includes no value for the
>   column, or an UPDATE statement sets the column to NULL, MySQL handles
>   the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional
>   tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables,
>   an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row
>   of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows will have been
>   inserted.
>
> If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit
>   default value for the column data type.

Comment: I see.Thanks.I have added two columns successfully。.